# Open Redirect Issue - Apache mod_wsgi Django

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am using apache server to host a django application (mod_wsgi)
The setup is configured as a reverse proxy.

When the url is hit on my site
[https://abc.mysite.net/http:%5C%5Cwww.google.com](https://abc.mysite.net/http%3a%5C%5Cwww.google.com), it redirects to google.com
Why does this redirect to google.com when

AllowEncodedSlashes is set to Off by default and 
https://abc.mysite.net/http:\\www.google.com throws HTTP 404 error

How are the url's different?

Comment: What is generating the redirect? If it is done in your code explicitly, it looks like may  not be properly escaping the URL in the redirect header returned. Anyway, better explain the source of the redirect.

Comment: If the url is not matched by django's url dispatcher, open redirect vulnerability is seen. %5C is single utf-8 encoded value for \